# How can /etc/hosts be used to associate multiple domains with a single IP?

Tags: hosts

I have a single IP (`81.174.66.48`) and I would like to use /etc/hosts to associate multiple domains with that IP.  Currently my hosts file looks like this:

```
81.174.66.48 nerto.it  nerto
```

I would like `eventlog.it` and `eventlog.in` to also be resolved to 81.174.66.48.  I tried making my hosts file look like this, but it didn't work the way I expected:

```
81.174.66.48 nerto.it  nerto
81.174.66.48 eventlog.it  nerto
81.174.66.48 eventlog.in  nerto
```

What it the proper setting to have in my /etc/hosts file so that `nerto`, `nerto.it`, `eventlog.it`, and `eventlog.in` all resolve locally to `81.174.66.48`?

Comment: that syntax is correct though

Comment: Upvote because this came up on the first page in Google - June 2018

Comment: Please explain how it didn't work to your expectations.  That looks correct.  What went wrong?

Answer (score 48):

Put all names for the same IP into a single line.

Assuming the 4 hostnames you want to access the IP via are `nerto`, `nerto.it`, `eventlog.in`, and `eventlog.it`, this should work:

```
81.174.66.48 nerto.it eventlog.in eventlog.it nerto
```

Comment: Is it possible todo the opposite? To add the same domain to multiple IP addresses in the hosts file.

Comment: @Bert though I see why you might wanna do that, it would not make any sense. How would your computer know which IP to choose?